# discord.py delete messages apart from pinned ones

Tags: discord.py

I want to delete all the messages in a channel apart from the pinned ones, I tried this solution

[On message delete message Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351265/on-message-delete-message-discord-py)

but it's the non-rewrite version so it's not working for me sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bulk delete (purge) a maximum of 100 messages at a time, but this should do the trick.

```py
@client.command()
async def purge(ctx):
    def not_pinned(msg):
        return not msg.pinned
    purged = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=100, check=not_pinned)
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully removed {len(purged)} non-pinned messages!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`TextChannel.purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge)
- [`Message.pinned`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.pinned)

Comment: Thanks! Small fix `return not msg.pinned` :D